# output of a 3D array in C++ code

Tags: c++

I am writing C++ code and have a question about the 3d array:

```
double ***excit_pn;
excit_pn = new double **[num_y];
for (int i = 0; i < num_y; i++)
{
    excit_pn[i] = new double *[num_x];
    for (int j = 0; j < t.size(); j++)
    {
        excit_pn[i][j] = new double[num_y];
        for (int k = 0; k < num_y; k++)
        {
            excit_pn[i][j][k] = 0;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
        {
            cout << excit_pn[i][j][k];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

codes above is part of my codes.
I want to test the values of array excit_pn. when I run the code, running results are all 4.26329e-312 rather then 0. but when I add

```
cout<<excit_pn[i][j][k];
```

after the line:

```
excit_pn[i][j][k] = 0;
```

, running results are 0.

my second question is:

```
for (int i = (num_y - num_el / 2); i < (num_y - num_el / 2)+num_el; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ts.size(); j++)
    {
        for (int k = (num_x - num_el / 2); k < (num_x - num_el / 2)+num_el; k++)
        {
            excit_pn[i][j][k] = excit_ptn[i - (num_y - num_el / 2)][j][k - (num_y - num_el / 2)];
        }
    }
}
```

there is an error in this part: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. excit_ptn has already been defined above:

```
ts_n = new double **[num_el];  //number of elements is num_x while the nonzero element is num_el
ye_n = new double **[num_el];
excit_ptn = new double **[num_el];
for (int i = 0; i < num_el; i++)
{
    ts_n[i] = new double *[ts.size()];
    ye_n[i] = new double *[ts.size()];
    excit_ptn[i] = new double *[ts.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < ts.size(); j++)
    {
        ts_n[i][j] = new double[num_el];
        ye_n[i][j] = new double[num_el];
        excit_ptn[i][j] = new double[num_el];
        for (int k = 0; k < num_el; k++)
        {
            ts_n[i][j][k] = ts[j] + con_delay[i][k];
            ye_n[i][j][k] = exp(-ts_n[i][j][k] * ts_n[i][j][k] / (2 * tv));
            excit_ptn[i][j][k] = p0* ye_n[i][j][k] * cos(2 * PI*fc*ts_n[i][j][k]);
        }
    }
}
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't use `std::vector` and forget the pointer madness?

Comment: This small piece of code eliminates all of that code you have now that calls new and in addition, initializes the arrays,: http://ideone.com/EX7ZVl A mere few lines. Not only that, there is no need to deallocate memory. –  PaulMcKenzie 5 mins ago

Comment: [This is how you can simulate 3d array in C++ using single std::vector](http://pastebin.com/yKCia0EX) @PaulMcKenzie: Your example also is not very good, because when you'll need to resize that, it will be major pain. Also, there's very large overhead of creating many std::vectors.

Comment: This is not a multidimensional array. It's a jagged array, like in Java. Also... what is the type of `ts`?

Comment: @SigTerm My example is to merely show how much code that the OP wrote can be totally eliminated, but also keep the same "internal" code that does the calculations.  Also, how much "pain" is there in calling `resize()`, as opposed to the `new[ ] / delete [ ]` gymnastics the OP's code would have to go through?

Comment: ts is a vector@celticminstrel .

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie is there any other method to keep the original space for initial array excit_ptn if I keep using the type : double ****excit_ptn?

Comment: @gugabrielle I don't know what you mean by "keep the original space".   Also, since you used `vector` for `ts`, why didn't you `vector` to create your other arrays (as the links given to you have shown)?  If you had done that, I doubt you would be having issues now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: " is to merely show how much code" I can understand that, but using "vector of vector of vector" to make multidimensional array is common bad idea of many newbie programmers, so it is better to kill that idea early. "Also, how much "pain" is there in calling" A lot, because you'll have to resize every row and every slice and if you forget that, the program will break. The idea of using nested vector is as bad as using nested nested blocks allocated with new. It is a pity that C++ doesn't come with multidimensional array by default. Perhaps boost has something?

Comment: @SigTerm If a newbie programmer used vectors, that is a shock in itself.  As a matter of fact it would be surprising that newbie C++ programmers would even know to use vectors this way.  Also `using nested vector is as bad as using nested nested blocks allocated with new.` Sorry, but I disagree with this.  If you want to get into the details of whether it is better to use a 3d vector over a 1d vector is one thing, but again, using a nested vector is far and away better than using `new` and `delete` and "3 star" programming.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  now I know that each time I define a new multidimensional array, the array will be allocated with new memory. If i want to call the previous defined array in the new array, what should I add in the code to avoid this kind of error or break?

Comment: @gugabrielle `now I know that each time I define a new multidimensional array, the array will be allocated with new memory.`  You're thinking too hard about this.  This part `now I know that each time I define a new multidimensional array,`  is all that you should be concerned with.  This part `the array will be allocated with new memory.`  don't worry about it.  You have a 3d array, just use it.  It is already set up and ready for you to use.  The vector knows how to clean up its own memory when you are done with it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: "If a newbie programmer used vectors, that is a shock in itself" Perhaps my standards are too high. But then again if newbie using vectors is a shock, then the industry is probably doomed. "but I disagree with this" Which is fine. It is matter of taste anyway. The reason why I think it is as bad as using new because you get burst of dynamic memory allocations, which will fragment heap AND will use much more memory than program really needs. Yeah, it will be cleaned up, but such patterns indicates lack of understanding of array layout, which smells like trouble in the long term.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: " new and delete and "3 star" programming." That's zero star programming. using `std::vector` (as in my example), is 2..3 stars since it is "that's what you were expected to do but could do that better". More star is finding boost or std container that does the job for you. Anyway, that's the matter of taste and I might have unreasonable standard, so there's little point of discussing that. Have a nice day.

Comment: thank you all so much! I have used a 3d vector to replace the 3d array excit_pn and the code runs well. but I still can not get a solution for the break: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. although I have an alternative method now

Comment: @gugabrielle Even though the code would be cut down tremendously by using `vector`, you are still vulnerable to memory access errors if you access an out-of-bounds index in the vector.

Comment: @gugabrielle The answer that was posted suggested you should make sure you are consistent with the amount of items you declared in the vector and the number of elements you are processing.  To do that safely, use `vector::size()` all the time to determine how far to loop, how many items are in the vector, etc.   To do that safely, once your vectors have been set up, drop using `num_x` and those other :"size" variables you're using.  They are no longer necessary, and as you can see from the answer given, are error prone since it now opens you up for bugs if you get the size wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your middle loop allocation, you have the loop end of t.size():

```
for (int j = 0; j < t.size(); j++)
```

but you allocate using the variable num_x.

```
excit_pn[i] = new double *[num_x];
```

These two quantities should be the same.

In your printing loop, you are using different dimensions again.  To be safer you should try to use the same dimensions everywhere when debugging especially.

Comment: thank you very much. I had checked the code many times and didn't find it.

Comment: you are welcome my friend!  i have not tried it yet but i believe there is a way to mark the answer 'accepted' here on stackoverflow as well as a way to acknowledge the help quantitatively.